# modal verb could usage

Tags: modal-verbs

> How **could** you do this to me? [It expresses outrage or anger]

While studying the usage of "could",  I found the above sentence. But I studied that "could" is used for hypothetical conditions.

So my question is, What is the unstated hypothetical condition in the given question, which made us to use "could" to give that mentioned meaning to this interrogative sentence.

Comment: [*Could*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/could) is used for hypothetical situations, but not ***only*** for them. There's nothing hypothetical about this sentence—it's simply the past tense of *can*, meaning *how **were you capable of** doing this to me?*

Comment: @JasonBassford  So as mentioned by someone, It expressing outrage or anger is false??

Comment: Outrage or anger can certainly be expressed by that sentence, but it's not so much a function of *could* as it is of tone of voice. Exactly the same sentence could also be a simple question.

Comment: @JasonBassford  Ok thank you, so that means this is just simple past tense form and any meaningful hypothetical interpretation is not at all possible???

Comment: No, hypotheticals are still possible. But it's not *either-or* when it comes to the word. The existence of the word alone doesn't determine if it's a hypothetical or not. You have to look at the context of the overall sentence and what's being described. Here's a hypothetical: *I would do it if I could.* Or *I could see it in the right situation.*